# password not geting hashed django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i'm using using customuser and trying to create user with drf but password not getting hashed. its returning raw password and because of that i can't use authentication its working with only user created by admin

```
class CustomUserMananager(BaseUserManager):
"""
Custom user model manager where email will be unique identifier

"""

def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    create and save user with given email and password
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('email must be set'))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save superuser with given email and password
    """
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('SuperUser must have is_staff=True'))
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('SuperUser must have is_superuser=True'))
    return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

serializer:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
              'mobile_number', 'password', 'is_active', 'user_type', 'otp')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

views:

```
    @api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def register(request):
    #permission_classes = [(AllowAny, )]
    serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.is_active = False
        user_otp = randint(999, 9999)
        otp_code = str(user_otp)
        email = request.data.get('email')
             send_mail(
            'Otp verification',
            otp_code,
            'jv',
            [email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        serializer.save(otp=user_otp)

        return Response({'response': 'User registered successfully, OTP sent to your Mail'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'f**w$%(m=pqt3=_r'


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.


# SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'users',
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    # 'allauth',
    # 'allauth.account',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount',


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'carry.urls'

TEMPLATES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_ROOT],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'carry.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    # }
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'carry',
        'USER': 'tboss',
        'PASSWORD': '5101',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'

    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
SITE_ID = 1


EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'as@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'asdasd'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('users.backends.EmailBackend',)
```

models.py:

```
 class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(_("user_type"))
    otp = models.CharField(_("otp"),max_length=10, default="0")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserMananager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

..................................................................................................

Comment: are you sure that the `CustomUserMananager` is tied-up with the `CustomUser`?

Comment: yes i have this AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser' in settings

Comment: Is it hashing when you add a user from the admin?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Can you share your `CustomUser` model? I think I see what might be causing it

Comment: added..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of things that may cause this in the way you pass data to the `create_user` function. The function requires `email, password, **extra_fields` but you're passing just `**validated_data` I'm suprised that didn't cause any errors.

To run step by step investigation, let's ignore the manager for once and try adding a new user directly in the `serializer` directly.

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                  'mobile_number', 'password', 'is_active', 'user_type', 'otp')
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            # Since no required fields from your model, i will just use the email, first_name, last_name and password to create
            # for now. I am assuming you're pass them too
            email = validated_data.pop('email')
            first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name')
            last_name = validated_data.pop('last_name')
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
    
            new_user = CustomUser(
                email=email,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name
            )
            new_user.is_active = True
            new_user.set_password(password)
            new_user.save()
    
            return new_user
```

> If this was able a add a new user with hashed password then you say
> for sure that the problem is coming from the manager function.

Comment: it still not working i'm getting this is admin ''Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm'' so i assume set_password not working and then i tried printing validated_data in create function it returns nothing. i'm not sure but i think even this function not running

Comment: Are printing it after you `pop` the fields or before

Comment: 1. I have your exact code working for me locally. 2. It can't be empty and the serializer passes it as valid. Do you have this on github?

Comment: its not on github btw if this working on your local then it might be some other issue. i'll check it. thanks for the help